# Angular change the state of a checkbox after user click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code that should set the checked value to false on click:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="checked" (change)="onChange()">
   `
})
export class AppComponent  {

  checked = false;

  onChange() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.checked = false;
    }, 1000)
  }

}
```

The problem is that if we click on the input and we wait for a second, it'll stay checked. Why is this happening? Why Angular doesn't change it to false again?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know does it worked for you or not. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 3):

Long story short Angular checkboxes are just broken : [Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9275)

If you however want to achive this effect i will recommend you to create your own custom component that will act the same way as a checkbox.

Here is one more fun example of [Checkbox madnes](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-with-at-least-one-value?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) try to interact with both "With track by" and "No track by" blocks and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that easily by using `[(ngModel)]="checked"`. Your code is working in the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvmecq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Please check that. Here is my code given below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="checked" [(ngModel)]="checked" (change)="onChange()"  name="horns">
    <label for="horns">Horns</label>
   `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
   checked = false;

  onChange() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.checked = false;
    }, 2000)
  }
}
```

Comment: @undefined I apologized for my callowness to explain why `[checked]="checked" ` is not working. Actually, every single time I have used `ngModel` to display and manipulate data. It works almost like real-time. :-(

Answer (score 0):

in angular you can manipulate dom using view child and element ref

first of all you need to import viewchild and elementRef in your component

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";    
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";    

@Component({  
selector: "my-app",  
templateUrl: "./app.component.html",  
styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]  
})  
export class AppComponent {  
@ViewChild("checkBox") el: ElementRef;  

onChange() {    
setTimeout(() => {  
  this.el.nativeElement.checked = false;  
 }, 100);  
}  
}
```

app.component.html

> <input type="checkbox" #checkBox  (click)="onChange()">

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uyehd1)